# Schedule same job after x sec on completion

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-priority-jobqueue

I am using com.github.yigit:android-priority-jobqueue. I am stuck how to schedule same job after x sec on completion or in onRun() call. Is there any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by adding delayInMs() method, while creating in constructor.

```
        super(new Params (PRIORITY).requireNetwork ().groupBy (Const.POOLING_QUEUE_GROUP).delayInMs (120000).persist ());//120 sec delay
```